# Completar datos de inserción SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, script, base-de-datos

Amigos buenas tardes, estoy tratando de hacer una inserción de datos de un servidor SQL a otro, ya tengo todo configurado y los servidores también están ya vinculados.

Les dejo ejemplo de mi Script

```
INSERT [192.168.100.24\SQLEXPRESS].[INT_IQWARE].[dbo].[T_DIARIO_TRANS]
SELECT
IdDiarioTrans,
FechaCreacion,
Fecha,
Folio,
Subfolio,
Habitacion,
Referencia,
IDTipoTransaccion,
TipoTransaccion,
ShortName,
Debito,
Credito,
Comentario,
Enviar,
SapDocEntry,
Linea,
procesar,
CuentaContable
FROM [T_DIARIO_TRANS]
WHERE (Fecha = (SELECT CurrentHotelDate FROM prProperty))
```

El problema es que tengo columnas que no lleno yo, que llenará el cliente desde otro proceso y pues el script no corre porque estas columnas que precisamente yo no lleno no aceptan NULL's

El error específico es el siguiente:

> The data value violated the integrity constraints for the column.

Mi pregunta es si hay alguna opción para rellenar estas tablas que quedan vacías con un 0, incluyendo una que es de tipo datetime. Para de esta forma insertar los datos correctamente y que luego el cliente ya inserte la información correcta en las columnas pendientes (las que yo quiero dejar a 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes dejar los valores de esas columnas directamente con valores por defecto como mencionas, por ejemplo si es un int 0 o si es una fecha con alguna fecha en particular, igualmente al no admitir nulos cuando se actualice luego con el otro proceso esos valores desaparecerán.

Ejemplo:

```
INSERT [192.168.100.24\SQLEXPRESS].[INT_IQWARE].[dbo].[T_DIARIO_TRANS]
SELECT
IdDiarioTrans,
FechaCreacion,
'01/01/2000',
Folio,
Subfolio,
0,
Referencia,
IDTipoTransaccion,
TipoTransaccion,
ShortName,
Debito,
Credito,
'',
Enviar,
SapDocEntry,
Linea,
procesar,
CuentaContable
FROM [T_DIARIO_TRANS]
WHERE (Fecha = (SELECT CurrentHotelDate FROM prProperty))
```